# Java: Does memory settings "Xmx + Xms + Metaspace" suggest how much memory a Server use?

Tags: java, jvm, wildfly

I started my Wildfly Server Groups and Found Linux Memory getting reduce on startup  of each servergroup.

I am not sure what of these xms, xmx, metaspacesize, maxmespacesize is considered while starting the servergroup which consume memory?

Earlier i was thinking it is Xms + Xmx used but i do not find that this combination is used.

Following is log of how i started severgroup 1 by 1 and memory it consume after successful start

```
Servergroup: Data
Arguments: -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 26055316 Kib
Memory After: 24862576 Kib
================
MDM
-Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 24753256
Memory After:24211048
================
Invoice
-Xms64m -Xmx800m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:24211048
Memory After:23284292
===============
General
-Xms64m -Xmx256m
Memory Before: 23284292
Memory After: 22753268
===============
Filemover
-Xms64m -Xmx1024m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 22753268
Memory After: 21797640
===============
Heretic
-Xms64m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 21797640
Memory After: 20092912
===============
24By7
 -Xms64m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:20092912
Memory After:18857712
==============
ERP
-Xms64m -Xmx800m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:18857712
Memory After:17263036
=============
Web
-Xms64m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:17263036
Memory After14835748

====TO CHECK AT END=========
Desk
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 14780344
Memory After: 12781144

=============
Timesheet
-Xms64m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:14739180
Memory After: 13239140
=============

batch
-Xms64m -Xmx1536m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before:13188052
Memory After: 10868944
=============
Agains checked at end
Desk
-Xms1024m -Xmx4096m -server -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m
Memory Before: 10868944
Memory After: 8476600
```

Can anyone help me in understanding same.

Comment: Are you trying to *predict* the whole used memory using just the values from those parameters? That won't be possible (or at least, you should assume a quite large error margin). JVMs use all kinds of memory pools and even just normal mapping of the shared libraries they use consumes memory. So while those numbers can give you a *hint* as to the magnitude of the total used memory, they can't give you a definite precise answer. Also note that "Xms" is "minimum heap size" and "Xmx" is maximum heap size, so if you care about maximum used memory, of those two only Xmx is relevant.

Comment: So does that mean, when servergroup starts with those parameters, then it does not block memory shown in those parameters? Earlier it has 512 Min heap; but i changed it to 64k and found no issue; also reduced Max Heap and found RAM gets free due to that. So i thought those parameters blocking something?

Comment: I don't know about wildfly and its server groups. All I can tell you is that those values alone are not sufficient to predict the total memory usage of Java process. That memory usage can also grow (if you give a smaller minimum heap, for example it might start smaller, but grow later). These numbers definitely *influence* how much memory your server will use, yes. And increasing them *tends* to increase the amount of memory used.